# In Spring is it good practice to put custom properties into the default application.properties/yaml file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-properties

I have a Spring Boot application. I want to add some custom properties.

Is it good practice to put these properties into the default `application.properties`/`application.yaml` file?

Or is it better to put them in a new properties file and keep only Spring properties in `application.properties`/`application.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using too many Spring properties, that someone might miss your custom properties, you can use the default one. It isn't a bad practice to do so.